# Rejoin to Domain after Re-imaging (without rebooting twice)?

Tags: windows, domain, disk-image

After reimaging a machine to replace failed hardware, I've found that often the device cannot connect back to the domain immediately.

To fix this, I modify the computer settings to make it join a bogus "ASDF" workgroup, which requires a reboot. Then upon logging in again, I rejoin it to the domain which again requires another reboot. After that, all works OK.

The question is: Is there a way to do this automatically without two reboots of the new machine? Even better is if the work can all be done from the domain controller. Then I (or another engineer) don't need to physically be at the machine if it is a client machine that is being replaced - could just have the technicians replace the hardware and I do the rest of the work from my desk.

*P.S. Some context: I work in a facility where production runs pretty much around the clock. We have dozens of servers and hundreds of client machines, some of them very old, running Windows XP or Server 2003. Some of these devices take 15 minutes to reboot, meaning 30 minutes to reboot twice. I realize the simple answer is "upgrade your devices" or "30 minutes isn't that long" but in a high-production environment, every minute counts. Additionally upgrading hundreds of devices is a large undertaking, not even considering the cost. Just looking for an automated way to do this, if there are any.*

Comment: I found out that you can join ambiguous workgroup, and without rebooting, join the domain. A reboot afterwards is always required however, so the trust relationship is formed and group policies get applied, but the first reboot can be skipped. If you want to keep the downtime on a location to a minimum, prepare a machien in advance, to place it, take back the old, and at HQ use VPN to put the machine in the domain if the site is not on the same domain.

Comment: Also: https://petri.com/add-computer-to-domain-powershell and powershell's `enter-pssession` could be interesting for you.

Comment: @LPChip Hm, don't know why I didn't think of that. After a new machine is built, have it connect to the bogus workgroup on the test bench instead of at its final destination. That at least eliminates half the work in the field. I guess if the 2nd reboot is always required, then I can't do much better than that, even with powershell. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an interesting article:
[Powershell Rocks, Rejoin computers in domain without restart](http://kunaludapi.blogspot.com/2016/03/powershell-rocks-rejoin-computers-in.html),
although I don't know if the described method helps in your environment.
You must have at least PowerShell version 3, meaning at least
Windows Server 2012 or windows 8.

- When the device cannot login to the domain account, login instead to a local
  administrator account
- Run PowerShell as Administrator and enter the following command:

  ```
    Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Repair -Credential (Get-Credential)
  ```

  You will need to input the domain user-name and password.
- Logoff and login to your domain account. It should work now.

The linked article contains a
[video](https://youtu.be/3M-UwCWUPdw)
that demonstrates the method.